# Powershell: Listing Individual Regex results into HTML Table

Tags: powershell

I am working with StatusHub API to get a result of incidents which includes an INC number that is embedded within the incidents.body element.

I have successfully managed to use Regex to pull a specific INC number which is unique:

```
$test = $INC_updates | Select-String -Pattern 'INC(\d+)' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.matches } | ForEach-Object { $_.value } | Select-Object -Unique
```

However now I am trying to compile those results into a HTML table where those INCs match the other incident descriptions, like name etc...

```
$Barrie = $SH_report | Where-Object { ($_.incident_updates -match "Barrie") -and ($_.incident_updates.body -match 'INC(\d+)' | Select-String -Pattern "INC(\d+)" -AllMatches | foreach { ($_.matches).value } | Select-Object -Unique) }
if ($Barrie) {
    write-host "High Sev Incidents found for Barrie" -ForegroundColor Green
    $Barrie | foreach {
        $Barrie_Tb += "<tr><td>$($_.title)</td> <td>$($_.start_time)</td> <td>Barrie Pocock</td> <td>$($_.incident_updates.body)</td></tr>`r`n"
    }
}
else {
    write-host "No High Sev Incidents found for Barrie" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

I get a result however it only puts one incident into the html table and repeats it across all cells and its not unique like it should be.

I hope I made some sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly confused by what you've posted here.

1. You're building a collection called $test which you are no using
   anywhere in the rest of the code, you posted.
2. You're building a collection of stuff, call $Barrie, then checking
   to see if $Barrie exists then passing that collection to a loop then asking for a variable called $Barrie_Tb that is not set anywhere in the code posted prior to the loop.
3. What is the values of $test/$Barrie/$SH_report/$Barrie-Tb?

I am surprised this is working at all. Take a step back and approach this one step at a time to make sure you are getting what you'd expect before proceeding to the next item.

***Removing this sample since it was just me riffing on what you originally showed forcing me to assume in writing this part***

***Updating based on our exchange below***

Analysis

```
# Use the $SH_report collection to extract only the $Barrie incident from $SH_report
$Barrie = $SH_report | 
Where-Object { $_.incident_updates -match "Barrie" } 

# Use the $Barrie collection info to look for the incident_updates.body from $SH_report collection
```

However, $Barrie is already populated with data from $SH_report, so, why are you doing this again?

```
if ($Barrie) 
{ $Barrie += Where-Object { $SH_report.incident_updates.body -match 'INC(\d+)' | 
Select-String -Pattern "INC(\d+)" -AllMatches | 
foreach { ($_.matches).value } | 
Select-Object -Unique }
```

Where is this ***$Barrie_Tb*** coming from? It is not shown or populated anywhere, well, you are not showing where or why. However, we know we'd do this type of stuff...

```
$Barrie_Tb +=
```

... to increases, the value of a variable by the specified value, add to a collection, object, etc., but again, the data is already there and this, by what you have posted is not defined, soooo....

```
# Use the modified $Barrie collection to output an HTML table
$Barrie | 
foreach { $Barrie_Tb += "<tr><td>$($_.title)</td> <td>$($_.start_time)</td> <td>Barrie Pocock</td> <td>$($_.matches)</td></tr>rn" } }
```

Id this .incident_updates.body is already in $SH_report, then why are you populating $Barrie at all and the reading it to $Barrie here:

```
{ $Barrie += Where-Object { $SH_report.incident_updates.body -match 'INC(\d+)'
```

Based on my read of what you presented, all the data you need is already in this $SH_report, so just use only that directly.

```
$SH_report | 
ForEach {$PSItem.incident_updates.body -match 'Barrie' -and 'INC(\d+)'}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion there. $test was just used as a test to see if the regex gives me the correct list of numbers. $SH_report is the variable uses select-object for the response on the Invoke-Restmethod request. $Barrie_Tb will be parsed into a HTML table later in the script.

Sorry for the confusion, if you want I can paste everything in?

Thanks for sending me your script, I have tried it and it gives me the following error:
"Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty array" - any ideas?

Comment: OK, and as for this... 'I have tried it and it gives me the following error: "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty array" ' I'd expect that since as noted, I have really no idea what you are processing. Post a sample of what is in this collection, $SH_report that you are then sending to $Barrie, which still looks redundant, in that you can pass it directly potentially simplifying this use case.

Comment: I've taken on what you said and this is where im currently stuck:

`$Barrie = $SH_report | Where-Object { $_.incident_updates -match "Barrie" }
if ($Barrie) {
    $Barrie += Where-Object { $SH_report.incident_updates.body -match 'INC(\d+)' | Select-String -Pattern "INC(\d+)" -AllMatches | foreach { ($_.matches).value } | Select-Object -Unique } 
    $Barrie | foreach {
        $Barrie_Tb += "<tr><td>$($_.title)</td> <td>$($_.start_time)</td> <td>Barrie Pocock</td> <td>$($_.matches)</td></tr>`r`n"
    }
}`
html table section $($_.matches) is not populating the regex values

Comment: always update your original post with code vs in the comment section.  You are still doing things that really do not line up. These are separate code blocks, two collections that are not related/hooked together in any fashion. You are using eth same collection name $Barrie 3 times and you are populating it twice. first here $Barrie = $SH_report and here $Barrie += Where-Object { $SH_report.incident_updates.body -match 'INC(\d+)'... why? Why are you adding more date from $SSH_report to $Barrie, that you've already populate with that data? This is why I aksed to have you post a data sample.